# Sharp edges while maintaining circular shape

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edges

I encountered a problem when modeling an inside of the wheel. 
The problematic part is where a spoke joins a rim. I want both the rim and spoke to have sharp edges, but when I crease the transition between them, the circular shape of the rim is no longer maintained there. And when I don't crease the transition it looks weird.
Here is how the creasing looks like without subsurf in edit mode:

[image]

If you would like to do some tests on the model, you can download it [here](https://mega.nz/#!bEVFFJ5R!Bfp5GkoMXNYVMcJyRYaUFjpYApmOvP4IOT0xLmIZaLg).
Is there a better way to get sharp edges than via creases?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14009/599

Comment: It seems to me [adding a loppcut to inner part](http://i.imgur.com/j3lDbkL.jpg) of the wheel will be enough to keep it smooth and round in your case. And, of course, several cuts on the external part

Comment: @MrZak It works well on the inner part! After reading the related post gandalf3 posted, I added loop-cuts on the facing side of the spoke too and merged them where they join rim. It kind of works better, since it gives me a [slightly sharper edge of the rim](http://i.imgur.com/m6inwPM.png). Probably the easiest solution is just to crease the edges of the spoke and uncrease the transition between the spoke and the rim. Then use loop-cuts on the inner sides (see [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/tVO5aN5.png)). Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Could edit to include a .blend? (upload to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using the *Edge Split* Modifier instead?

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if it would help but, you can try separating the inside of the rim by selection and take off the subsurf in the inside of the rim.